# oracle: deny naked sql statements

Tags: permissions, trigger, oracle-12c

I'm looking for a solution in oracle 12c to deny `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements on tables.

I would only provide `SELECT` privileges and exec rights to execute procedures which `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` rows from tables. So I can ensure clean rows.

It there a way to implement triggers to deny naked sql statement access?

Comment: Just revoke the privileges

Comment: I want that the owner of the schema can not execute nacked sql till he disable the trigger which protect the table.

Comment: Normal security setup procedures for a database will lock the account for the schema that owns the tables before the database is "open for business".  Either that, or you spend a lot of money for Oracle Database Vault.

Answer (score 1):

The account that owns the database objects should not be used *by anyone* to access that data.  (Except by you and your fellow DBAs, who know what they're doing!)

A simple, "additive", security model is far easier to understand and maintain.

Create "Application" and "User" roles and grant the appropriate levels of access, then grant these to user and application accounts.

```
create user data_owner ... ; 
create table data_owner.table1 ... ; 

create role app_role_1 ; 
grant select, insert, update, delete on data_owner.table1 to app_role_1 ; 

create role user_role_2 ; 
grant select on data_owner.table1 to user_role_2 ; 

grant app_role_1 to application_1_account ; 
grant user_role_2 to fred, wilma ;
```